# Storing Bank Account information or third party services providing data store and payout service

Tags: encryption

I am going to launch a website in India which would need users bank account numbers and IFSC for me to pay some money to them. I am concerned with the security and safety in storing such information.

Is there any best way to do this? I have already read so many questions about this which talks about so many options but no one recommends the best.

Some posts talked about using third party payout processors but I couldn't find any such service.

Can someone please suggest a good option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this yourself unless you have an incredible business case and can comply with PCI-DSS and all relevant regional regulations and laws both in India and where your customers reside.  Doing the complete math it's unlikely to come out profitable, but it might.

This is an existing and well-established outsourcing problem.  ADP (Automated Data Processing) does outsourced payroll which may be a fit depending on your need.  There are also many other payment processors like Paypal and Klarna who do this allowing more ad-hoc payer payee relationships.  There are also general payment processors typically used by retailers and the service industry who can manage inbound payment.  I don't think payment processors generally handle paying out from a central payer as a typical use case.

Comment: Thanks @Alain. That is what my exact concern is, I don't want get into that law :). Usually payment processors provide the payment gateway/accept payment solutions but not the function to transfer to others (I may be wrong) and so I am still looking for third party services who can manage this for me.

Comment: Paypal and Klarna (possibly others like them) allow authenticated peer to peer transfers without a checkout.  You would use their API to do a transfer from your central account to each recipient based on their email.  Be careful not to make this a "push button, receive bacon" situation ;) https://pressbuttonreceivebacon.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/push-button-receive-bacon2.png

Comment: PayPal Single Payout https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-single-payout/ seems the perfect fit for my requirement. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

**A good option: don't do it.**

The advice sounds dumb and you may have seen it in the posts you read but writing a secure application is not easy, you need to take zillion things into account.

Writing a secure application which will store sensitive financial information is not only difficult, but you now may run into liability issues. Depending on the country you may be responsible for losses of your customers after someone has hacked into your system.

You could either use some hosters which give you the ability to build an e-commerce site and maybe start from there, or have a reputable company writing it for you.

If you really, really want to do it yourself, start with [OWASP](http://owasp.org). You also want to have a look at PCI-DSS. It is not exactly relevant in your case but the [PCI-DSS SAQ-EP](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_A-EP_v3.pdf) is interesting, it will hive you a hint on what is expected for e-commerce applications.

But really don't.

Comment: Thanks @WoJ. I think risk seems to outweigh rewards here in managing information myself. I will look may be to outsource that payout function. Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Paypal peer-to-peer transfer as mentioned by @alain-odea is the perfect fit for me so accepting that answer. Your inputs were also valuable, thank you very much.